# Array in postman for test script

Tags: javascript, arrays, build-automation, postman-testcase

I am creating test script for automation in postman.I want to create array. I have response, which has multiple id's String. How can create array for to verify ids.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have this code:                                                                                            <Identifiers>
           <Identifier = “1234”>
           <Identifier = “5678”>
          <Identifier = “9101”>
          <Identifier = “1213”>
          <Identifier = “1415”>
</Identifiers>                                                                                                                      How I can verify these ID's in my response? Do I need array, or to do one by one?